# Using Emacs for $PAGER?

Tags: emacs

There are lots of places in UNIX where programs call out to the program in $PAGER (usually `less` or some similar command) to display some output. It's certainly true that many of the most common uses have an Emacs replacement (in the case of `man`, for example), but I'd still like a general way to use Emacs as my system-wide pager. Ideally this would mean that calls to PAGER end up in an Emacs temporary buffer similar to *Help*, a read-only buffer you can navigate around and dismiss by pressing "q".

I usually run a shell through M-x shell, so my envisioned use case is that typing a command like "man foo" in the *shell* window will bring up the man page in another window, more or less exactly like how the built-in *Help* system works.

Comment: `less` is `more`, but there is also `most` another pager which has emacs-like bindings and some nice color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For general use of `$PAGER`, you might be interested in [e-sink](https://github.com/lewang/e-sink).

For the specific case of man pages, it's better to use Emacs's built-in man mode as you note. I have this in my `.bashrc`:

```
man () 
{ 
    if [ "$TERM" == "eterm-color" ]; then
        emacsclient -e "(man \"$1\")";
    else
        command man "$@";
    fi
}
```

Since you use `shell-mode` rather than `ansi-term-mode` like I do you will either have to make this use emacsclient all the time, or do something like `(setenv "WITHIN_EMACS" "1")` in your `.emacs` file so you can switch on `$WITHIN_EMACS` instead.

Comment: You don't need to set your own variable, emacs sets `INSIDE_EMACS` for you in `M-x shell`. See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html)