# How to view man pages using emacs when invoking man command in command line?

Tags: emacs, pager, manpage

I would like to view man pages using emacs when invoking man command.
I modified the pager parameter in `/etc/man.conf` PAGER to `emacs`.

But, it doesn't work. Is there anything I should modify ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Emacs for $PAGER?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406721/using-emacs-for-pager)

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, emacs cannot read STDIN into a buffer, meaning

`cat foobar | emacs`

does not work in any case. So setting your PAGER variable to 'emacs', or 'emacs -nw' does not do the job.
Only way around I see is to write the `man` output into a tmp-file and then load that file into emacs:

`man find > tmp-file; emacs tmp-file`

You could alias this.
For example, assuming a tc-shell, and a directory called 'tmp' in your home-path, you can put the following line into your `~/.tcshrc` file:

`alias man '/usr/bin/man \!* > ~/tmp/tmp-file; emacs ~/tmp/tmp-file; rm ~/tmp/tmp-file'`

So next time you call `man find`, emacs will fire up.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs has a "Man mode", which can be invoked by `M-x man RET` and then typing in your command.

Answer (score 3):

You can profit from emacs's function `man`. Just define a function in bash that will run emacs that will call it:

```sh
function man () {
    emacs -e '(man "'"$1"'")'
}
```

You might want to call `emacs -nw` or even `emacsclient` instead.

Comment: Also worth considering: `emacs -eval "(woman \"$1\")"`, which uses emacs' elisp based man instead of the external man program.

Comment: @ataylor This opens the man buffer as a popup, how can I maximize it (in the script, of course)?

Comment: @YoujunHu: What do you mean by "does not work"? What error do you get? It works for me.

Comment: @choroba  : The error I got:  symbol's function defintion is void: \(man\ \"find"\)

Comment: The version that works for me: `emacs -nw --eval '(progn (man "'$1'") (delete-window))';`

Comment: another working version: `emacs -nw --eval "(progn (man \"$1\") (delete-window))"`